# The stackexchange.com user activity tab still links to /review-beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, stackexchange.com

Seen in my activity log at https://stackexchange.com/users/1048581/michaelb958?tab=activity, subtab <kbd>reviews</kbd> (and also reproducible on [Community ♦'s activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity), so I'm guessing it happens for everyone):

> ```
> <a ... href="http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/3308207">
> ```

I thought `/review` was well out of beta by now... The link still *works* (301 Moved Permanently to `stackoverflow.com/review/...`), but this is going to bug me now that I've found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, this will be fixed in the next build.